# OG Meta Tags (Facebook Sharing): How to scrape from one site, but link to another?

Tags: html, css, facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to make a Facebook share button that links to one webpage, but pulls OG metadata from a separate webpage. Is this possible? This is what I have tried so far:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Title" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="Article" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000615328448/3f4d11442e83bb34f90124b64b8ee57b.jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Description" />
    <meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.facebook.com"/>

</head>
    <body>
        Sample Text

    </body>
</html>
```

As of now this only pulls meta data from Facebook, and not from this HTML doc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO - this website is for help improving existing code. What have you tried already?

Comment: I updated it with what I have tried

Comment: Facebook pulls the og tags from the link you share

Comment: `og:url` must be the URL that the meta data is provided under. You can only do it the other way around – and redirect human visitors arriving at that URL to somewhere else. (Either per JavaScript, or via a server-side redirect that makes an exception for the FB scraper based on its User Agent.)